# Javascript frameworks for frontend development

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

This has probably been asked in the past, but I can't quite figure out what to Google to get the answer.

I am writing a web application where the entire backend is already available as an API. I am wondering what javascript frameworks would be good for writing the frontend. What javascript frameworks would work well for the frontend development?

I don't need the entire stack like Meteor and Node.js offer, I simply need some logic controllers and views. Is Node.js good for this? Do other frameworks exist? I will likely have business logic on the frontend so having a framework that is good for this would be nice.

Comment: "Javascript frontend framework" - the most obvious search query in the world. And the first result has more than enough framework titles.

Comment: I agree there are a lot of frameworks there but the problem is I don't know which are heavily tied to their own DB. Meteor for instance seems less useful if you aren't taking advantage of realtime updating which requires you use their DB. When I look at other mvc js frameworks I don't know what others fall into that boat and I was hoping someone else with experience with a few frameworks could give some insight.

Answer (score 9):

20 JavaScript Frameworks Worth Checking Out

**[Sproutcore](http://www.sproutcore.com/)**

Sproutcore powers a lot of high profile apps including MobileMe amongst others. Sproutcore has a steeper learning curve compared to the other options but makes up for it with developer productivity once he/she has learned the ropes. This framework boasts a UI framework, the market standard MVC architecture and well written documentation.

Related links:
Using SproutCore 2.0 with jQuery UI 
Build a Micro-Blog with SproutCore
When To Use SproutCore, and When Not To

**[Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/)**

Cappuccino was created by the 280North team, now owned by Motorola. This framework gained significant coverage with the release of the 280Slides — built completely with Cappuccino.
This framework varies dramatically from the others in that a developers doesn’t need to understand or work with any of the front end trifecta — HTML, CSS or the DOM. All you need to master is the framework!

**[JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)**

Built on jQuery, JavaScriptMVC is a veteran in the front end frameworks battlefield, dating back to 2008. Featuring a familiar, and obvious, MVC architecture, this framework is quite full featured with support for code generators, testing and dependency management.

**[Asana Luna](http://asana.com/luna/)**

Luna is one of those hush-hush private frameworks that people have been talking about. And for good reason, I must admit.
The framework features a lot of niceties including an evolved MVC architecture, pubsub, caching, routing and authentication.

**[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)**

Backbone supplies structure to JavaScript-heavy applications by providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and connects it all to your existing application over a RESTful JSON interface.

**[qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/)**

qooxdoo is a universal JavaScript framework that enables you to create applications for a wide range of platforms. With its object-oriented programming model you build rich, interactive applications (RIAs), native-like apps for mobile devices, light-weight traditional web applications or even applications to run outside the browser.

**[Spine](http://maccman.github.com/spine/)**

Spine is a lightweight framework for building JavaScript web applications. Spine gives you a MVC structure and then gets out of your way, allowing you to concentrate on the fun stuff, building awesome web applications.

**[ActiveJS](http://www.activejs.org/)**

ActiveJS is a JavaScript application framework that provides local and REST based data modeling and pure DOM view construction with back button and history support along with framework agnosticm and lack of external dependencies.

**[Eyeballs](http://github.com/paulca/eyeballs.js)**

eyeballs.js is a slim javascript library designed to sit on top of a javascript framework, such as jQuery or Prototype. eyeballs.js can sit on top of an already implemented web app with a well thought out object model. It can also be used to build standalone javascript apps, backed by HTML5 local storage or something like CouchDB.

**[Sammy](http://sammyjs.org/)**

Sammy.js is a tiny JavaScript framework developed to ease the pain and provide a basic structure for developing JavaScript applications. Sammy tries to achieve this by providing a small ‘core’ framework and an ever-growing list of plugins for specific functionality.

**[Choco](https://github.com/ahe/choco)**

Choco brings the MVC to the client side! A Choco app consists of only one HTML page, all the interactions are managed by Javascript. Your UI only uses HTML and CSS!

**[Agility](http://agilityjs.com/)**

Agility.js is an MVC library for Javascript that lets you write maintainable and reusable browser code without the verbose or infrastructural overhead found in other MVC libraries. The goal is to enable developers to write web apps at least as quickly as with jQuery, while simplifying long-term maintainability through MVC objects.

**[Angular](http://angularjs.org/#/)**

Angular supports the entire development process, provides structure for your web apps, and works with the best JS libraries. With angular, the view and data model are always in sync — there is no need for manual DOM manipulation. Angular is small, weighing in at 60kb, is compatible with all modern browsers and works great with jQuery.

**[ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)**

Ext JS 4 brings a whole new way to build client applications, by introducing the popular model-view-controller pattern to Ext JS. By allowing the separation of data management, logic and interface elements, Ext JS 4 makes it easier for even large development teams to work independently without worrying about stepping on each other’s toes. Ext JS 4 ships with a helpful MVC guide to get started.

**[Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)**

Knockout is a JavaScript library that helps you to create rich, responsive display and editor user interfaces with a clean underlying data model. Any time you have sections of UI that update dynamically (e.g., changing depending on the user’s actions or when an external data source changes), KO can help you implement it more simply and maintainably.

[Jamal](http://jamal-mvc.com/)

Jamal is a set of conventions and small javascript libraries to archieve a complete separation of html, css and javascript in your web application. Jamal is built on jQuery and inspired by MVC frameworks like Ruby on Rails, CakePHP and its derivatives.

**[PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/)**

PureMVC is a lightweight framework for creating applications based upon the classic Model, View and Controller concept. Based upon proven design patterns, this free, open source framework which was originally implemented in the ActionScript 3 language for use with Adobe Flex, Flash and AIR, is now being ported to all major development platforms.

**[TrimJunction](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/TrimJunction)**

The open source Junction framework is a conventions-over-configuration, synchronizing web MVC framework for JavaScript. TrimPath Junction is a clone or port of the terrific Ruby on Rails web MVC framework into JavaScript.

**[CorMVC](http://www.bennadel.com/projects/cormvc-jquery-framework.htm)**

CorMVC is a jQuery-powered Model-View-Controller (MVC) framework that can aide in the development of single-page, web-based applications. CorMVC stands for client-only-required model-view-controller and is designed to be lowest possible entry point to learning about single-page application architecture.

**[batman](http://batmanjs.org/)**

batman.js is a full-stack microframework extracted from real use and designed to maximize developer and designer happiness. It favors convention over configuration, template-less views, and high performance by simply not doing very much. It all adds up to blazingly fast web apps with a great development process; it’s batman.js.

**Source:** http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/20-javascript-frameworks-worth-checking-out/